# I want to create more than one horizontal view like flipkart main page

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-studio

I have to create like flip cart main page, so I need use more than one horizontal view how to create that programmatically in android. In that horizontal view inside Vertical orientation using images, price, product name will display in android.

Thank in Advance
I just created Like this as mention below code:

```
 public void shopimages()
{

   /* GradientDrawable drawable = new GradientDrawable(
   GradientDrawable.Orientation.TOP_BOTTOM,new int[] {R.color.shadow,Color.WHITE,R.color.shadow});
    drawable.setShape(GradientDrawable.RECTANGLE);*/
 //   drawable.setStroke(3, Color.BLACK);
    //drawable.setCornerRadius(8);

  //  drawable.setColor(0xFFFFFFFF); //white background
    // border.setStroke(1, 0xFF000000);



  //  categories = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.categories);

    /* child layout of horizontal*/
    LinearLayout[]  lLayout = new LinearLayout[8];

    for(int j=0;j<lLayout.length;j++ ) {
        lLayout[j] = new LinearLayout(getActivity());


        LinearLayout li=new LinearLayout(getActivity());
        li.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        li.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

        /* Heading text for each horizontal images*/
        name=new TextView(getActivity());
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        params.setMargins(0,150,0,0);
         name.setLayoutParams(params);
        name.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
        name.setText("kani"+j);
        name.setPadding(10,10,10,10);
        name.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ff1319ff"));
         li.addView(name);
        li.setTop(50);
        root.addView(li);

        /*end*/

        /* child layout created dynamically*/
       // lLayout[j].setBackgroundDrawable(drawable);
        sv = new HorizontalScrollView(getActivity());
        sv.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
        lLayout[j].setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        lLayout[j].setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
         sv.addView(lLayout[j]);
        /*end*/


        t = new TextView[10];
        names=new TextView[10];
        price=new TextView[10];
        existingprice=new TextView[10];

        img = new ImageView[10];
        /*create the layout for textveiw and image view*/
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams image=new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        image.topMargin=50;
        image.leftMargin=15;
        image.rightMargin=15;
        image.bottomMargin=10;
        image.width=200;
        image.height=150;


        LinearLayout.LayoutParams dim = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        dim.topMargin=20;
        dim.leftMargin=15;
        dim.rightMargin=15;
        dim.bottomMargin=10;
        dim.width=200;
        dim.height=80;
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams dim2 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        dim2.leftMargin=40;
        dim2.width=200;

        LinearLayout.LayoutParams dim3 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);




        /*end*/
        /*using for loop to run the rexxtview*/
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            LinearLayout imageVertical =new LinearLayout(getActivity());
            imageVertical.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
            imageVertical.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

            img[i] = new ImageView(getActivity());
            img[i].setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
            img[i].setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
            img[i].setImageResource(mThumbIds[i]);
            t[i] = new TextView(getActivity());
            img[i].setLayoutParams(image);
            t[i].setLayoutParams(dim);
            t[i].setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            t[i].setTextSize(14);
            t[i].setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ff1319ff"));
            t[i].setText("YOHOHO: " + i);
            // name
            names[i] = new TextView(getActivity());
            names[i].setLayoutParams(dim2);
            names[i].setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            names[i].setTextSize(14);
            names[i].setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ff1319ff"));

            /*names[i].setEllipsize (TextUtils.TruncateAt.END);*/
            names[i].setText("lightweight" + i);

            //horizontal linear layout
            LinearLayout pricelayout=new LinearLayout(getActivity());
            pricelayout.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

            pricelayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);


            //price
            price[i] = new TextView(getActivity());
           // price[i].setLayoutParams(dim3);
            price[i].setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            price[i].setTextSize(9);
            price[i].setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ff1319ff"));
            price[i].setText("Rs.2000");

            // existing price
            existingprice[i] = new TextView(getActivity());
            /*existingprice[i].setLayoutParams(dim3);*/
            existingprice[i].setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            existingprice[i].setTextSize(9);
            existingprice[i].setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ff1319ff"));
            existingprice[i].setPaintFlags(existingprice[i].getPaintFlags()| Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG);
            existingprice[i].setText("Rs.5340");

            pricelayout.addView(price[i]);
            pricelayout.addView(existingprice[i]);



            imageVertical.addView(img[i]);

            imageVertical.addView(t[i]);
            imageVertical.addView(names[i]);
            imageVertical.addView(pricelayout);
           // imageVertical.addView(existingprice[i]);
             lLayout[j].addView(imageVertical);


        }
        /*end*/

        /* parent layout we can add the child view */
        root.addView(sv);

    }
```

Comment: you can take horizontally listview where you can adapt data as vertically.

Comment: If i use horizontal listview it is possible to create more than one dynamically to show that view

Comment: Use recyclerview with Horizontal orientation. You can use more than one horizontal recyclerview to show your items. I am doing that at the moment. ListView is such a pain.

Comment: Here are couple of libraries [First](https://guides.codepath.com/android/implementing-a-horizontal-listview-guide) [Second](https://github.com/MeetMe/Android-HorizontalListView)

Comment: I don't want to display in static way.I want to display dynamically Via Json